# Opinion about using SESSION with PHP

Tags: php, session

I need opinion about using session with php. I'm useing session to store data. For instance - **configuration**:

1. First I'm loading data from config.ini to `$_SESSION['config']`
2. Then I'm using custom session class to get specific data from `$_SESSION['config'][$key]`;

This is config function:

```
public static function load_config($process_sections = FALSE)
    {
        $array = parse_ini_file(CONFIG . DS . 'config.ini', $process_sections);

        if ($array)
        {
            $_SESSION['configuration'] = $array;
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['configuration'] = array();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

function config($key, $default = NULL)
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['configuration']))
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['configuration'][$key]))
        {
            return $_SESSION['configuration'][$key];
        }
        else
        {
            return $default;
        }
    } 
}
```

That same is with user object. I'm getting user data not from DB, but API, and storing it in `$_SESSION['user']`. When **user object** is **constructs**, I'm attributing all properties just from `$_SESSION['user'][...]`, for instance:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->initUser();
}

private function initUser()
{   
    if (Session::is('user'))
    {
        return $this->setUserData(Session::get('user'));
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}    

private function setUserData($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        if(property_exists($this->_name, $key))
        {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Properties are defined in class. I'm doing it just on time, when object is constructing. Is that right practice? It's working very good for me but I doubt if my method overolads server.

Comment: Are you storing user configuration or server configuration in sessions???

Comment: Hmm... application configuration, not server config. For example, default language, app version, default controller, page title, etc.

Comment: isn't that a bit redundant? I mean, every time a user starts a session, you duplicate the configuration by starting a new session.. ?

Comment: Are you asking if every new session contains configuration data? Yes, because I need quick access to this data in my application. Is there a better way? I think access to session data is more quick than parse config file everytime when I need it. So I parse it once, when app starts. Maybe i'm wrong? I'm confused.

Comment: It is clever indeed, but... what if a user clears their browser data? then the browser would request a new session, a different one... and then the settings saved in the old session are lost. That is why people usually use databases to handle per user/client data. Sessions are stored on the server, but they are accessed, when the correct browser visits the page, in which you access a specific session.

Comment: OK but settings can't be modified by web user anyway, this is read only. Only developer/administrator can it. When user starts new session that is OK, application will be restarted and it's desirable side effects ;-) User will be logged out. I can't use DB because of project requirements.

Comment: Please read my post again, I added code where I'm putting `config.ini` to `session`